# How to correctly enter the data-target id in php echo

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, echo

I am trying to open a bootstrap modal window containing product image and information. My problem appears to be the #uoc-modal inside the data-target. Can some please tell me how to correctly enter the data-taget id inside an echo?

`echo '<a "data-toggle='modal'", "data-target='#uoc-modal'" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question code, you should escape it

```
echo '<a "data-toggle=\'modal\'", "data-target=\'#uoc-modal\'" href="\' . get_the_permalink() . \'">';
```

But, I think this should work

```
echo '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uoc-modal" href="'.get_the_permalink().'">Modal</a>';
```

But anyways, you don't need `data-target` attribute for `<a>` element. Just use `href` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I had an extra comma in my original code that kept it from working. Escaping didn't work it couldn't get the permalink

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
echo '<a "data-toggle=\'modal\'", "data-target=\'#uoc-modal\'" href="\' . get_the_permalink() . \'">';
```

Good evening